# Node.js res.json() and res.send(), not working but still able to change status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, post

I've read almost every thread about this and still can't figure out what's wrong.

Any information, either by res.send(), res.json(), res.write() res.end(), doesn't get received on the client side. But I know the info is getting sent and stored because the database is updating, and I know there is a response because I can console.log the object and if I change the server's status code (200 vs 201, for example) the response printed on the client side reflects that.

The client sends the email by post to the server.

```
var object = JSON.stringify({
      email: myemail,
    });
    await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/subscriber/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: object,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res => {
      res.json();
    console.log(res);})
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

When I run this, these are the logs:

Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:4000/api/subscriber/", redirected: false, status: 201, ok: true, …}

Success: undefined

Here's the relevant server side code

Path calls a function

```
app.post('/api/subscriber/', (request, response) => {
   db.createSubscriber(request, response);
   })
```

Then the info is stored in the database and the response is sent.  Here's where the problem is -- anything I try to send here -- even random text doesn't show up, but I know the communication is happening because I can see the status code logged from the client side when I change it.

```
const createSubscriber = (request, response) => {
   const { firstname, lastname, email } = request.body;
   const text = //SQL query
   const values = [firstname, lastname, email]
   pool.query(text, values, (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
          console.log('error');
          response.status(400);
          throw error;
      } else {
          response.status(201).json({status:201,id:results.insertID});
      }
      return response;
   })
}
```

I've tried different ways of sending, assigning variables and using .then, a ton of small tweaks.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `fetch()` in the browser, `res.json()` returns a new promise and you have to wait for that promise with `await` or `.then()` in order to get the data from it.

So, you would do it like this:

```
await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/subscriber/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: object,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Also, on server-side, your error handling needs some fixing.  Change this:

```
  if (error) {
      console.log('error');
      response.status(400);
      throw error;
  }
```

to this:

```
  if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      response.sendStatus(400);
  }
```

You have to always send a response.  You were setting an error status, but never sending the response.  And, there was no use for the `throw err` at all.  There was nothing catching it so it wasn't doing any good.

Comment: Oh my god was it really a freaking print statement all along? fml. That did fix it tho, thanks so much.

Comment: @Nikki - No, it wasn't a print statement.  It's because you were calling `res.json()`, but not doing anything with the resulting promise that it returns.  My code adds that promise to the promise chain (by returning it) so the subsequent `.then()` gets its result.